# Swift - Combining Predicates

Tags: ios, swift, nspredicate

Is there a way of combining predicates in Swift? For example:

```
let predicate1 = NSPredicate("self.label = 'foo'"))
let predicate2 = NSPredicate("self.label = 'bar'"))
let combinedPredicate = NSPredicate("self.staticTexts.elementMatchingPredicate(%@).exists AND
  self.staticTexts.elementMatchingPredicate(%@).exists", predicate1, predicate2)
```

That gives me an error saying predicates cannot be arguments to other predicates. Is there another way to combine them?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You'll need [`NSCompoundPredicate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCompoundPredicate_Class/):

```
let predicate1 = NSPredicate(format: "self.label = 'foo'", argumentArray: [])
let predicate2 = NSPredicate(format: "self.label = 'bar'", argumentArray: [])
let compound = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: [predicate1, predicate2])
```

Comment: Sorry I messed up the question. I edited it correctly now.

Answer (score 7):

```
let predicate1:NSPredicate = NSPredicate("self.label = 'foo'")
let predicate2:NSPredicate = NSPredicate("self.label = 'bar'")
let compound:NSCompoundPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: [predicate1,predicate2])
self.filteredArray = self.array.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(compound)
self.table.reloadData()
```

You can use this also as per your different requirement

```
let compound:NSCompoundPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(orPredicateWithSubpredicates: [predicate1,predicate2])
```