# Swift Predicate AND and OR in one

Tags: swift, nspredicate

What I'm wanting to do is combine two or queries with an and query

WHERE (id contains[cd] %@ OR name contains[cd] %@) AND manu = %@"

So far I have it working with one of the ors and the and, but I can't figure out how to do both

```
let predicate1 = NSPredicate(format: "id contains[cd] %@", searchedText)
let predicate2 = NSPredicate(format: "threadManu = %@", manu)
predicate = NSCompoundPredicate.init(type: .and, subpredicates: [predicate1,predicate2])
```

Comment: Compare [Create complicated NSCompoundPredicate in swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46388393/create-complicated-nscompoundpredicate-in-swift-3)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift - Combining Predicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31708540/swift-combining-predicates)

Comment: Why don't you put them in one `NSPredicate(format:)`?

Comment: Tried that originally and it would give incorrect results

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need two `NSCompoundPredicate`.

```
let predicate1 = NSPredicate(format: "id contains[cd] %@", searchedText)
let predicate2 = NSPredicate(format: "name contains[cd] %@", searchedText)
let predicate3 = NSPredicate(format: "threadManu = %@", manu)

let predicateOr = NSCompoundPredicate(type: .or, subpredicates: [predicate1, predicate2])
let predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(type: .and, subpredicates: [predicateOr, predicate3])
```